# Visual Studio Code: How can I exclude files from Quick Open but not from Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a TypeScript project that I edit using Visual Studio Code, and I found that I can exclude files from *Quick Open* (`cmd+P`) by configuring `files.exclude` like this:

```js
"files.exclude": {
    "dist/**/*.js": true
}
```

This hides the compiled files when I use *Quick Open* which is what I want. The problem is that this code also hides the file from the File Explorer.

Is there a setting that excludes the files from *Quick Open* and *Search* but still list them in Explorer? Ideally using a dim color indicating "private", like Atom does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

please try,

```
"search.exclude": {        
        "dist/**/*.js": true
    }
```

Comment: Please explain this!

Comment: files.exclude excludes from the explorer, search.exclude excludes from find.

Comment: @user but how to exclude an extension from the search (eg: `.lnk`)? This failed: `"search.exclude": {        ".lnk": true,   },`

Comment: @JinSnow you can try `"*.lnk"`

Answer (score 2):

Open settings (cmd/ctrl + ,) and then search for "exclude" and press "Add Pattern"

[image: exclude from quick open]

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to happen on a project basis, you just need to create a folder named `.vscode` in your project root, and add a `settings.json` file in it.

The file is equivalent of VSCode's own user settings file but just works for that specific project. You can then commit those files to your repo and settings will be applied for every team member using the IDE.

For example:

```
// <project>/.vscode/settings.json

{
  "search.exclude": {
    "public/**/*": true
  }
}
```